# A question regarding shapes and infinitesimals

Tags: geometry

I have found myself quite confused about this.  It started when I was reading a book called Mathographics by Robert Dixon which explains different methods for deriving pi. One of the methods involves rectifying a circle which had me wondering about making shapes with the same perimeter measure.
At first, I assumed that if you take the perimeter of any object and manipulate it into any shape, it should always maintain the same area...but apparently this doesn't work with circles and squares..or even triangles.  Is it the case that any equilateral shape with same perimeter measure will never maintain the same area?  And why not?  I know mathematically it doesn't work.  I've done the math to prove it doesn't work with circles and triangles...but why??  Where is my confusion stemming from?

Comment: Can we clarify the statement *any equilateral shape with same perimeter measure will never maintain the same area*?  What *exactly* do you mean by that?  An answer to the effect of "it won't maintain the same area if we ___ it" would help.

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the [isoperimetric problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

Comment: And what do you mean by "any equilateral shape"?  Any polygon with all sides equal?  Clearly the statement is false: you can have differently shaped equilateral hexagons, say, with the same area and perimeter.

Comment: The perimeter measures the "stuff" on the boundary of an object, the area measures the "stuff" on the inside. Intuitively, if you had a two-dimensional object in the shape of a circle that you could take most of the "stuff" out of the inside of, analogous to deflating a mylar balloon, you would end up with something with the same perimeter but much less area. I just can't imagine why someone would say that manipulation of the perimeter of an object should _always_ result in the same area. This only makes sense if you have a particular kind of manipulation in mind; what did you have in mind?

Comment: Why *would* it?  Obviously if you collapse a fence or square box or a jump rope circle you can "flatten" anything out to have little to no area.  So intuitively "pumping up" the area is a matter of filling things up with larger angles-- collapse the angles to 0 or 180 and the shape becomes a line but pumping them to right angles or obtuse angles we are making them as large as possible.  So "equilateral" forces our hands a little bit, fair enough, but the number of sides force or angles.  fewer sides = Sharper angles = more "collapsed"; more sides =wider angles= more area.  As pure intuition...

Comment: I think I'm being confused because I imagine like water filling the inside of some object.  Then, if I push on the side of the object, the volume remains the same.

Comment: @fleablood , but if you continue to flatten a square, it's edges should move outward and you'd be making a really flat rectangle that would still maintain the area...i think...maybe my intuition is just stupid ?

Comment: Why would a flat rectangle maintain the same area?  1 inch by 23 inches is 23 square inches.  12 inches by 12 inches is 144 square inches. Much bigger.  Take a rectangular bookcase, remove the back supports, watch it tilt over in a trapezoid until it collapses to the ground.  It's area gets smaller as it falls.  Now Take a stack of books and pile them to make a rectangle.  Slide the books over.  The sides are longer so the perimeter is more.  But the area is the same.

Comment: Take a rectangle.  Cut it in half.  You have two new rectangles.  They have the same area.  But the new line you cut adds to the perimeter. Take a chess board (area 62 perimeter 32) cut off the two corners.  Paremeter is still 32 but the area is now 62.  Take a rectangle.  Take the edge in your hand a slide it over a few feet.  The area stays the same but the two sides were stretched longer.   Take a tape measurer, measure the perimeter of your couch, now roll the tape measurer up and put it in your pocket--- can you put the couch in your pocket?

Comment: Take a jigsaw puzzle and measure the perimeter of every piece.  Put the jigsaw puzzle together and measure the perimeter of the completed puzzle.  Take two right triangles with sides 5,12, and hypotenuse 13.  Attach them at the hypotenuse, you have a rectangle with sides 5 and 12.  Now attach them at the 5 inch side.  You now have a parallelagram with sides 12 and 13.  This is a much bigger parameter but it must have the same area.  Take a plastic bag and lay it flat.  0 volume.  Now blow it up like a balloon.  Same surface area, more volume.  Yes, your intuition *is* faulty.

Comment: Look at this image. https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS72Z_iNjyhKM9QYrWjb1SNsTFeOJCr6i3HQEw09Z2BwueB4-5WsQ You have a 12 pointed star **inside** a 12 sided polygon.  It is *inside* so its area must be less.  But count the sides.  For every short side of the 12-gon the star has two very long edges.  The star has **MUCH** larger perimeter but **SMALLER** area.

Comment: Okay 2nd to  last post: "I think I'm being confused because I imagine like water filling the inside of some object. Then, if I push on the side of the object, the volume remains the same"  But the surface area becomes *bigger*.  If you had a picture on the water balloon and you squeezed it the picture would bulge out.  The only way to keep the image from bulging out would be to deflate the balloon and *decrease* the volume.  It's like the mylar balloon David K had in mind.

Comment: last post: "but if you continue to flatten a square, it's edges should move outward"  yes if you flatten a square while maintaining perimeter the edges move out *linearly* in one dimension but the area depends on *two* dimensions.  Overal affect is a loss of area.  You are increasing length to become $\frac {a + x}{a}$ times longer.  But the height becomes $\frac {a - x}{a}$ times shorter.  They are *inversely* proportional but ... oh, I'm going to make this an answer...

Comment: One very last comment.  Notice if a mylar balloon is fully inflated you *can't* squeeze it.  This is because it must *maintain* volume.  But if you squeeze one dimension, to maintain volume the other edge must move a *different* amount and the surface does not stretch.  It can not be squeezed because maintaining volume does *NOT* maintain perimeter.  It is the *exact* opposite.  Maintaining volume *distorts* perimeter (and maintaining perimeter *changes* volume).  Nearly always.

Answer (score 0):

If $P_1P_2\dots P_n$ is a regular polygon. Let $O$ the center of the polygon. Let $\alpha=2\pi/n$, and $OP_1=r$.
The perimeter is $n\times 2r \sin(\alpha/2)=n \times 2r \sin(\pi/n)$.
The area is $n \times 2r\sin(\alpha/2)\times r \cos(\alpha/2)=n \times 2r\sin(\pi/n)\times r \cos(\pi/n)$.

If $Q_1Q_2 \dots Q_k$ is another regular polygon with same perimeter than $P_1P_2 \dots P_n$. The center is $O$ too. Let $OQ_1=r'$.Then $n \times 2r \sin(\pi/n)=k \times 2r'\sin(\pi/k)$.

If the area is the same, $n \times 2r\sin(\pi/n)\times r \cos(\pi/n)=k \times 2r'\sin(\pi/k)\times r' \cos(\pi/k)$.

So $r \cos (\pi/n)=r' \cos(\pi/k)$.

and $k \times 2r'\sin(\pi/k)=n \times 2r \sin(\pi/n)$.

So $k \sin(\pi/k)\cos(\pi/n)=n\sin(\pi/n)\cos(\pi/k)$.

So $k \tan(\pi/k)= n \tan(\pi/n)$.

But if $k, n \geq 3$, as $x \mapsto \tan(x)/x$ is strictly increasing on $]0, \pi/3]$, we can't have $k \tan(\pi/k)= n \tan(\pi/n)$, and so we can't have same area and same perimeter for $P_1\dots P_n$ and $Q_1 \dots Q_k$ if $n \neq k$.

Comment: Ok this answers my question, I think.  It only holds for regular polygons.  Thank you.

Comment: No, it doesn't even hold for regular polygons.  A square with sides 3 will have area 9 (and perimeter 12).  But an equilateral triangle with sides 4 (and perimeter 12) will have area $\frac 12*4*(\frac{\sqrt 3}24) = 4\sqrt3 \ne 9$.  The more side so that $n*x = 12$ the larger the area will be.  A circle with circumference 12 and radius $6/\pi$ will have area $36/\pi \approx 11.46$ will be the largest any shape with perimeter 12 can have.

Comment: I meant to say that my statement was true only for regular polygons.. As the proof by marco2013 shows. But you can make irregular polygons have same area and same perimeter.  Like Tetris pieces

Answer (score 0):

You intuition is faulty.

Consider a square $12$ inches long and $12$ inches high.  It has perimeter $48$ inches and an area $144$ square inches.

Squeeze it so that it is now $1$ inch high and $23$ inches long.  It still has perimeter $48$ inches.  But its area is now $23$ square inches.  Where did the extra $121$ square inches go?

In the comments you commented that by flatten it we are pushing one edge out by $11$ inches but shrinking the other by $11$ inches so the area should stay balanced.

But increasing $12$ inches by $11$ inches is proportionally much less significant that *de*creasing $12$ inches by $11$ inches.

We've increased the side by $\frac {12 + 11}{12} = \frac {23}{12} = 1.916666..... $ times longer.

We've decrease the other side to be only  $\frac {12 -11}{12} = \frac 1{12} = .083333....$ times as long.

So the area will now be $1.91666666..... * .0833333 = 0.159722222....$ as much.

Indeed the original area was $12*12 = 144$ and the new area is $12*12*\frac{12 +11}{12}*\frac{12 - 11}{12} = 12*12*\frac{23}{12}*\frac{1}{12} = 23*1$.

The "secret" is similar to the one of calulating wins vs. losses as percentages.  $a -x$ is a *different* percentage of $a$ then $a + x$ is of $a$.  So increasing one side by $x$ and decreasing the other $x$ are maintaining the same *absolute* value but not the same *proportional* values.  So the area will not maintain proportionality.  But the absolute perimeter will stay constant.

Or in *other* words.  $a*a = a^2$ but $(a+x)(a-x) = a^2 - x^2 \ne a^2$.  Area is *not* preserved when perimeter is.

(And vice-versa.  $a*b = Area$ but $(a+x)\frac {ab}{a+x} = ab = Area$ while  $\frac{ab}{a+x} \ne b - x$.  Area is preserved but perimeter is *not*.)